# c# Is there a option to filter a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to know if there is a possibility to filter a listbox. I mean it in such a way that is i add an item and the name is already in the listbox that you get a messagebox.show that tells you"Item already in the listbox". And that it won't be added twice.

Comment: what do u mean by adding a item in the list box? you adding items to it on a button click ? or something similar..?

Comment: Yes i'm adding a item from another listbox.

Comment: before adding an item loop through the existing items and check if the new one is already present in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to iterate throug the items as the Items collection of the ListBox implements the "Contains" method.

```
if (listBox1.Items.Contains(Item))
{
     MessageBox.Show("ListBox already contains Item");
}
```

"Item" is in this case the Item from the other ListBox

Update. You could write:

```
if (listBox1.Items.Contains(listBox2.SelectedItem))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ListBox already contains Item");
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.SelectedItem);
        }
```

Comment: "Item" is the Item from the other ListBox. I'll update my post.

Comment: It did not work, I can still add twice but maybe that's on my side this is what is made from youre code: private void list_selected_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (list_selected.Items.Contains(item))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ListBox already contains Item");
            }
        }

Comment: This is becasue you check the SelectedItems collection. You need to check the Items Collection. Edit: Sorry missread your Source. Where do you get the item object from?

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample code try and implement it in you code

```
 ListBox.ObjectCollection ListItem1= ListBox1.Items; 

 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchBox.Text)) 
 {
      foreach (string str in ListItem1)
      {                
         if (str.Contains(SearchBox.Text))
         {
             msgbox;
         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean with searchbox?

Comment: your text box from which you are entering item

Comment: i get this error: Error 1 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' because 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 0):

Use data binding might be one of the solutions:

```
List<string> SomeData=...
var filtered=SomeData.Where(...);  // <-- Your filtering condition here
listBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(choices, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event/method which adds list items inside your listbox you can add something like:

```
// search for list item in the listbox which has the text
ListItem li = theListBox.Items.FindByText("yourListItemName");

if (li != null)
{
// if list item exists display message
  MessageBox.Show("ListBox already contains item with the name");
}
else
{
  theListBox.Items.Add("yourListItemName");
}
```